# Fastest way to sum matrix of 1's (ones) and 0's (zeros) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

If I have data structure of say:

```
1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
```

... is there a way to count the 1's (or add them since this value is the same as counting) without looping through the entire array and its sub-arrays?

I'm creating the structure like so:

```
int[][] grid = new int[N][N];
```

No libraries are allowed to solve this.

Comment: You need to access each element to check if it's a 1 or not. Hence, you have to use a loop.

Comment: I doubt it. What are your requirements?

Comment: You might be able to find some utility method to do this. But *that* will be looping through the entire array, so it would simply be hiding the looping from you, not not doing it too.

Comment: You can convert it to a stream but that still would  akin looping.

Comment: Why the restrictions like having to use `int[N][N]`and no libraries?  Is this a homework question?

Comment: Do you mean without writing a loop (`while` or `for` or `do`) or with a Java8 stream operation that doesn't look like a loop but does loop internally?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
int[][] grid = {
    {1, 0, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1},
};
long onesCount = Arrays.stream(grid)
    .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)
    .sum();
System.out.println(onesCount);  // -> 4
```

Comment: Instead of filtering and returning the count, it would be easier to use IntStream#sum.

Comment: You should stick with either `Arrays.stream()` or `[Int]Stream.of()`.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**

When you are creating this array, you should keep track of the number of 1's during insertion time.

I know its not probably the way you wanted it, but it will avoid having to loop through the resulting data structure.

Comment: You can also sort an array in O(1) time by populating it with sorted data.

Comment: "If I have data structure of say"